# Empty array is truthy or not in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, boolean, comparison

I'm a bit confused by the following results, could someone kindly point out what happened under the hood?
why Boolean([]) will return true?
and loosely compare empty array to a Boolean
[] == false would evaluate to true?
but strict comparison would evaluate to false??

This is the part I don't get it

Thanks so much!

```
Boolean([])
//true

[] == false
//true

[] === false
//false
```

Comment: Empty array in javascript is truthy inorder to check for array you have to check the length of array     ```if ([].length) {// do something } else {// do something else} ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Boolean([]) // => true
```

- Here, [] (Array is object type) is converting to boolean. Since []
  has the reference value, after conversion is is true.

.

```
[] == false // => false
```

- Here, Equality operator loosely check values. Since both sides are
  different types (object and boolean) and  one of side is boolean, So
  it will covert to (0 or 1) and compare to other side. It will be
  equivalent to +[] == +false, which will be 0 == 0, will be true

[Check MDN document for more details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality)

```
[] === false // => false
```

- Here, Strict Equality operator. Will check for Type and value Since
  both are different types, it will be false.

Comment: THANKS! Concise explanation

Comment: @siva Please correct  [] == false // => false.. you added it not false its true some typo

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way to check reliably is to use the length property.

```
[].length // 0, falsy

['something'].length // 1. truthy
```

See the official [spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison) for more info.

Comment: but why Boolean([]) will return true? 
and loosely compare empty array to a Boolean
 [] == false would evaluate to true?  but strict comparison would evaluate to false??

This is the part I don't get it

Comment: Its not all logical. See the above linked repo. There are many example of these things that are just crazy. It's goof to know they are there when looking for a weird error though.